# replace labels of levels in contour with a marker

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, contour

Is it possible to replace texts of levels in a contour with markers like circle and star in matplotlib?
I am using this code for showing levels. But I want to replace zero with a star in the plot!

```
levels = [0,10]

cs1 = ax0.contourf(p, l,p_difference,levels, cmap=cmap, vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax)
cs = ax0.contourf(p, l, p_difference, cmap=cmap, vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax)

ax0.clabel(cs1, fmt='%2.1d', colors='k', fontsize=12)  # contour line labels
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fmt` parameter of [`clabel()`](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.0/api/contour_api.html#matplotlib.contour.ContourLabeler.clabel) can be a dictionary mapping a level to a string. Such string can use any unicode character available in the font used. Here is an example:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

p = np.linspace(0, 10, 400)
l = np.linspace(0, 10, 400)
pp, ll = np.meshgrid(p, l)

p_difference = np.sin(pp + 0.06 * np.random.randn(400, 1).cumsum(axis=0)) \
               * np.cos(ll + 0.06 * np.random.randn(1, 400).cumsum(axis=1)) * 6 + 5

levels = [0, 10]

vmin = -1
vmax = 11
cs1 = plt.contour(p, l, p_difference, levels=levels, cmap='seismic', vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax)
cs = plt.contourf(p, l, p_difference, levels=np.arange(-1, 12, 1), cmap='seismic', vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax)

fmt = {0: '☆', 10: '★'}
plt.clabel(cs1, fmt=fmt, colors='w', fontsize=20)
plt.colorbar(cs)
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Comment: so beautiful figure! ^__^
Thanks for the answer.